# Tomcat initialized and starts on different ports

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, springrunner

I have a problem with my end to end test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:test.properties"})
public class ConfigurationTest {
  ...
}
```

`test.properties`:

```
server.port=56156
```

If I run my test locally, everything is fine. But if I run this test on VM, every time I receive an error:

```
06:22:20 ***************************
06:22:20 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
06:22:20 ***************************
06:22:20 
06:22:20 Description:
06:22:20 
06:22:20 The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 0 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
```

Before running that test I'm sure that the port is free, and no process is using it. But when I run this test locally, I find this two lines in logs, maybe looks bad:

```
2019-01-31 13:34:18,746 | INFO  | main       | TomcatWebServer          | Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (https)
...
2019-01-31 13:34:30,751 | INFO  | main       | TomcatWebServer          | Tomcat started on port(s): 56156 (https) with context path ''
```

It's looks like tomcat started twice? It's possible?